# Várias cidades em um projeto

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde!

Queria umas dicas.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de um site de classificados, quero utiliza-lo com várias cidades aqui da região, como eu posso fazer para que no mesmo site o usuário selecione sua cidade?

Por exemplo, o usuário seleciona São Paulo o site direciona para os classificados de São Paulo. Rio de Janeiro a mesma coisa, etc...

O que me indicam?

Obrigado!

Comment: Alguma dúvida em específico?

Comment: Como separar isso num banco de dados?

Comment: Basicamente uma tabela com os municípios e um campo `id_municipio` (exemplo) na tabela de anúncios

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, você pode fazer com url's amigaveis passando o parâmetro da cidade direto na url, exemplo:

www.meusite.com.br/saopaulo
www.meusite.com.br/riodejaneiro

você pode fazer via o evento onchange do javascript, ao selecionar a cidade em uma lista (select html) ele redireciona para a cidade escolhida.

via AJAX e dai nem precisaria recarregar a página, apenas selecionava a cidade e já atualizaria o conteúdo no container que você especificar.

Comment: Mas e como separar isso no BD?

Comment: Crie uma tabela cidades, e na tabela de classificados relacione o ID da cidade com o anúncio.